# Showing Z is not complete in the 2-adic metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that $\mathbb Z$ is not complete in the 2-adic metric.

I don't know where to start with this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hints: if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, what can you say about the $2$-adic representation of $n$? Can you construct a Cauchy (in the $2$-adic metric) sequence of integers that does not have that property?

Comment: What do you mean by 2-adic representation of n?

Comment: Write $n$ as $\sum a_i2^i$ for $a_i\in\{0,1\}$.

Comment: ahh right I seewhat you mean, will think about that thank you

Comment: Still not really getting it

Comment: Do you know how to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't complete in the ordinary metric?

Comment: not particularly this is quite a weak topic for me

Comment: Nevermind think I have it now